# Javascript to make a component to dynamically follow another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically rendered div/span that needs to follow a particular component e.g. a textbox.  Currently it is set to a particular coordinate on the page and it is shown as appearing right beneath the textbox.  But it no longer appears that way when a div above the textbox gets collapsed/expanded (i.e. it goes above/under the textbox).

Think of it as a search result area appearing under a search result box after clicking the search button, but the search result area moved when a random div above the search text box collapsed/expanded.

I'm pretty sure that a bit of javascript would fix this.  I tried googling for it, but struggling to come up with decent keywords (and my search phrase didn't really return me much).

The div/span in question is rendered in jQuery dynamically.  I was wondering what does the quick solution look like?

Thanks.

Comment: Any code? Diagrams? Errors? Your question is a little ambiguous in terms of exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I "think" I understand your question... can you not wrap the textbox and div/span in another div and position that instead so it follows?

A javascript solution is not very pretty as you'd have to re-position the "results" div every time another div was collapsed or anything changed on the page that would affect the position of the textbox. If that is what you want to do then you could use the offset() function.

```
var myInputOffset = $('#MyTextBoxID').offset(); // Get the position of the input field relative to the document
$('#MyDivID').css({top: myInputOffset.top + 50; left: myInputOffset.left }); // Position the div
```

NB: The div should be positioned absolute and the 50 is an arbitrary number to shift it down lower than the input field.

Comment: thanks for the code. I pretty much have something like that, and it turned out the way I described it: when a div above the search stuff expands/collapses, the search result box seems to stay stationary, or "floats" when I scroll the page up and down.  If I refresh the page, the search result box repositioned itself.  I wanted the search result box to stay constantly below the search text box regardless of whether the things above the search area collapses/expands. I was thinking putting some code under an event in javascript, but... no such event fits the bill.

Comment: @BeraCim - Not sure if it helps but there's a property monitoring plugin that you may be able to attach to the search text box to update the div's position whenever the position of the search text box changes... but without seeing how you've implemented this - I can't say whether it'll be of any use. Here's the link anyway: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/478985.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link. I thought of the idea to re-draw the result box constantly too, but as the link described it looks a bit choppy.  However it does the job for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
$('<div>Search completed</div>').insertAfter('#searchBox');
```

This will insert the DIV immediately after the `<textarea>` with an id of "searchBox".

Answer (score 0):

For the div above the text box and search result area, have it hidden when it is "shrunk" instead of not there at all. I think that may help keep things in place.

It sounds like the text box is staying in the same position and the bottom div is coming up? If so, is there anything around the text box that might make it behave that way? (or is the text box moving up and the bottom div even higher?)

[Also see CSS position property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp)

> fixed -   Generates an absolutely
>   positioned element, positioned
>   relative to the browser window. The
>   element's position is specified with
>   the "left", "top", "right", and
>   "bottom" properties

You can use this to keep your bottom div positioned regardless of what is changing around it.